# How to I access emojis in a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to access emojis in a message, but keep on getting an error

Here's my code:

```
 client.on('message', (recievedMessage) => {
   if (recievedMessage.author == client.user) {
    return
   }
  recievedMessage.channel.send("Message recieved, " + recievedMessage.author.toString() + " : " + 
  recievedMessage.content)

  recievedMessage.react("")
  recievedMessage.guild.emojis.forEach(customEmoji => {
   console.log(`${customEmoji.name} ${customEmoji.id}`)
  recievedMessage.react(customEmoji)
 })

})
```

The error i am getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'emojis' of null at Client.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your using discord.js v12

```
client.on('message', (recievedMessage) => {
   if (recievedMessage.author == client.user) {
    return
   }
  recievedMessage.channel.send("Message recieved, " + recievedMessage.author.toString() + " : " + 
  recievedMessage.content);

  recievedMessage.react("");
  recievedMessage.guild.emojis.cache.forEach(customEmoji => {
   console.log(`${customEmoji.name} ${customEmoji.id}`);
  recievedMessage.react(customEmoji);
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'emojis' of null at Client.` means `message.guild` was undefined

So this probably means that your bot recieved a message on a DM channel,

so to fix all you need to do is validate if it's in a guild:

```js
client.on('message', (recievedMessage) => {
   if (recievedMessage.author == client.user) {
    return
   }
  recievedMessage.channel.send("Message recieved, " + recievedMessage.author.toString() + " : " + 
  recievedMessage.content)

  recievedMessage.react("")
  if(recievedMessage.channel.type !== "dm") {
    recievedMessage.guild.emojis.forEach(customEmoji => {
     console.log(`${customEmoji.name} ${customEmoji.id}`)
     recievedMessage.react(customEmoji)
   })
  }
})
```

Most people usually don't accept messages in dm to begin with:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
   if(msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
});
```

Also another possible error that PokemonLeader mentioned, was `.cache` if you are using v12.